# How to process high resolution photo in Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: windows-phone

I'm trying to load images from FileOpenPicker and save it to the WritableBitmap to work with it later. It works, but when I load high res image (for example jpg 2592x3888 ), my app crushes. And it takes too long to process big images. So my question is: what am I doing wrong here? What is the best approach?

---

```C#
StorageFile file = args.Files[0];
using (IRandomAccessStream stream = await file.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read))
{
    App.context.Image = new WriteableBitmap(1, 1);
    stream.Seek(0);
    int width = (int)Frame.ActualWidth;
    int height = (int)Frame.ActualHeight;
    App.context.Image = await BitmapFactory.New(1, 1).FromStream(stream);
    App.context.Image = App.context.Image.Resize(width, height, WriteableBitmapExtensions.Interpolation.NearestNeighbor);
    this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(RecognizingPage));
}
```

PS: This is really a working version - I will not be using this width and height.

Comment: Nokia has a high resolution image library (maybe this can help you): http://developer.nokia.com/resources/library/Lumia/imaging/working-with-high-resolution-photos.html

Comment: Thank you, but "problem with writeableBitmapEx" is still here. In this article image is loaded (and decoded to smaller) BitmapImage. I would like to load it to WriteableBitmapEx. Is there a easy and efficient way to to this? WriteableBitmap don't have DecodePixelWidth and Height :(

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code to decode image for lower resolution.

```
using (var storageStream = await storageFile.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.ReadWrite))
{
var encoder = await BitmapEncoder.CreateAsync(BitmapEncoder.JpegEncoderId, storageStream);
var pixelStream = yourWriteableBitmap.PixelBuffer.AsStream();
var pixels = new byte[pixelStream.Length];
await pixelStream.ReadAsync(pixels, 0, pixels.Length);

encoder.SetPixelData(BitmapPixelFormat.Bgra8, BitmapAlphaMode.Ignore, (uint)yourWriteableBitmap.PixelWidth, (uint)yourWriteableBitmap.PixelHeight, 48, 48, pixels);
await encoder.FlushAsync();
}
```

you can refer this question for more details:
[WriteableBitmap SaveJpeg missing for universal apps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25343475/writeablebitmap-savejpeg-missing-for-universal-apps)